# Why they are Using this 'public User getUserById(int userId)'?

Tags: java, mysql

I get this program in this site:(**http://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/**). And my doubt is why they are using this one **public User getUserById(int userId)** maybe we can live this part, nothing has been change form the output then,why are they using? whats the big deal buddy? any one take me out of this problem,...

```
package com.daniel.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.daniel.model.User;
import com.daniel.util.DbUtil;

public class UserDao {

    private Connection connection;

    public UserDao() {
        connection = DbUtil.getConnection();
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("insert into users(firstname,lastname,dob,email) values (?, ?, ?, ? )");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getDob().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteUser(int userId) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("delete from users where userid=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, userId);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
                    .prepareStatement("update users set firstname=?, lastname=?, dob=?, email=?" +
                            "where userid=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(user.getDob().getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, user.getUserid());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
            while (rs.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return users;
    }

    **public User getUserById(int userId) {
        User user = new User();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.
                    prepareStatement("select * from users where userid=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, userId);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                user.setUserid(rs.getInt("userid"));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                user.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }**
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You might also want to correctly tag your questions in the future, why was this tagged `wordpress`??

Comment: To get single user data passing id, So what is your doubt?

Comment: already they are using update and add. then, why and where they are passing the details...@gowtham

Comment: i am ushing this  QBUsers.getUsersByIDs(usersIDs, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() ((ApplicationSingleton)getApplication()).setDialogsUsers(users);
  but get     '{"current_page":1,"per_page":1,"total_entries":0,"items":[]}'

Comment: is there any solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is need of this function. because java has encapsulation mechanism & for batter arcitacture they use MVC where `User` class is model here.

here `public User getUserById(int userId)` simply collect all information from database & return as a variable `User` (which behaves like model) now no need to re connect to database for further detail.

Comment: hey buddy, your right. But, for what purpose... they are using already update and add functions, then why its using.

Comment: update is for **update DATABASE** add is for Inserting & this is for **SELECT** very simple.

Comment: hey, i know that yeah, I've not mention that, i'm telling update and add functions are already using, then why using 'public User getUserById(int userId)'.

Comment: @jmail To fetch the data about a particular user from the database ? Sometimes you just want to retreive something from a database. Sometimes you want to add something to the database. Sometimes you want to update something that's already in the database. If you want to update something, the example code you have linked to first retrieves the User using  getUserById(), so you can change/edit an existing user.

Comment: hmm fine buddy,yeah, i understand that,... Anyway thanks @nos

Comment: If my ans satisfy please accept it.

Comment: @buddy i am getting   '{"current_page":1,"per_page":1,"total_entries":0,"items":[]}' on this i am using QBUsers.getUsersByIDs(usersIDs, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>()